# Gutenberg: Block validation failed

Tags: wordpress

Based on the information you provided, it seems like there are two issues here:

Validation Error:
The validation error you are seeing in the console after reloading the admin panel and saving the post is related to the custom block's content validation. The error suggests that the block validation failed because it expected a specific structure, but the saved content does not match that structure.

Unable to Re-select Post in Admin Panel:
The second issue you mentioned is that after saving the post, you are unable to reselect the post in the admin panel. This could be related to how the selected post data is stored and retrieved in the block attributes.

```
(function (wp) {
  const { registerBlockType } = wp.blocks;
  const { withSelect } = wp.data;
  const { __ } = wp.i18n;

  registerBlockType('ideapro/custom-block', {
    title: __('Custom Post Block'),
    icon: 'hammer',
    category: 'design',
    keywords: [],
    attributes: {
      selectedPostId: { type: 'number' },
      postTitle: { type: 'string' },
      postContent: { type: 'string' },
      postDate: { type: 'string' },
      postImageURL: { type: 'string' },
    },
    edit: function (props) {
      const { attributes, setAttributes } = props;

      function updateSelectedPost(event) {
        const postId = event.target.value;
        if (!postId) {
          // If no post is selected, reset the attributes
          setAttributes({
            selectedPostId: null,
            postTitle: '',
            postContent: '',
            postDate: '',
            postImageURL: '',
          });
          return;
        }

        // Fetch the selected post data from the WordPress REST API
        wp.apiFetch({ path: `/wp/v2/posts/${postId}` }).then((post) => {
          setAttributes({
            selectedPostId: postId,
            postTitle: post.title.rendered,
            postContent: post.excerpt.rendered,
            postDate: post.date,
            postImageURL: post.featured_media_url,
          });
        });
      }

      // Ensure props.posts is not null or undefined before using map
      const posts = props.posts || [];

      // Render the block editor
      const selectOptions = [
        wp.element.createElement('option', { key: '', value: '' }, __('Select a post...')),
        ...posts.map((post) =>
          wp.element.createElement('option', { key: post.id, value: post.id }, post.title.rendered)
        ),
      ];

      const selectedPostContent = attributes.selectedPostId ? 
        wp.element.createElement('div', { key: 'selected-post-content' },
          attributes.postImageURL && wp.element.createElement('img', { src: attributes.postImageURL, alt: attributes.postTitle }),
          wp.element.createElement('h3', null, attributes.postTitle),
          wp.element.createElement('div', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: attributes.postContent } }),
          wp.element.createElement('p', null, new Date(attributes.postDate).toLocaleDateString())
        ) : null;

      return (
        wp.element.createElement('div', { key: 'custom-block-editor' },
          wp.element.createElement('label', null, __('Choose a Post:')),
          wp.element.createElement('br', null),
          wp.element.createElement('select', { onChange: updateSelectedPost, value: attributes.selectedPostId || '' }, selectOptions),
          selectedPostContent
        )
      );
    },
    save: function (props) {
      // The save function will render the post content on the front-end
      const { attributes } = props;
      const { selectedPostId, postTitle, postContent, postDate, postImageURL } = attributes;

      if (selectedPostId) {
        return (
          wp.element.createElement('div', { className: 'wp-block-ideapro-custom-block' },
            postImageURL && wp.element.createElement('img', { src: postImageURL, alt: postTitle }),
            wp.element.createElement('h3', null, postTitle),
            wp.element.createElement('div', { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: postContent } }),
            wp.element.createElement('p', null, new Date(postDate).toLocaleDateString())
          )
        );
      }

      return null; // Always explicitly return null if the condition is not met
    },
  });

  // Fetch the posts to populate the select dropdown
  // This function will be called when the block is added to the editor or refreshed
  // We are using the withSelect higher-order component to fetch the posts from the REST API
  // and pass them as props to the block's edit function
  wp.hooks.addFilter('editor.BlockEdit', 'ideapro/custom-block', withSelect((select) => {
    return {
      posts: select('core').getEntityRecords('postType', 'post', {
        per_page: -1,
        status: 'publish',
      }),
    };
  }));
})(window.wp);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.